# Pause every 25th URL being scraped using Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I'm scraping a website with different URLs (about 1000) and only able to get 25 query due to website limitation (of course!). I have used `Function.InvokeAfter` with `Number.RandomBetween` but no luck.

However, I found that if I wait/pause about an hour or so after the 25th URL, I could query again. Now, I would like to automate that part.

I created a column called Wait with a value on every 25th row on the URL_List table with a number between 60-90 so that every 25th URL, I can have it wait 60 to 90 mins but I don't know how to implement. If I could replace `Number.RandomBetween(10,20)` with `Number.RandomBetween(10,[Wait])`. Or also open to other ideas.

Here's what I have done so far:

Function for `fGetResults`:

```
let Scrape=(URL) =>

    let
        Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(URL)),
        Data0 = ()=>Source{0}[Data],
        #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Function.InvokeAfter(Data0, #duration(0,0,0,Number.RandomBetween(10,20))))

    in
        #"Transposed Table"

in Scrape
```

Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="URL_Table"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each fGetResults([URL_List]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Merci beaucoup...

#############
UPDATE
#############

I did some more digging and [found this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5ee7437-aa73-4333-abce-d4604d4c3d13/can-i-make-interval-of-webcontens-?forum=powerquery) and [this](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/11/14/waiting-between-web-service-requests-in-power-query/). Instead of a Wait column with a number from 60-90mins after 25th URL or so, I just place a "yes".

`WaitMinutes` function:

```
let
    Wait = (minutes as number, action as function) => 
            if (List.Count(List.Generate(() => DateTimeZone.LocalNow() + #duration(0,0,minutes,0), (x) => DateTimeZone.LocalNow() < x, (x) => x)) = 0) then null else action()
in
    Wait
```

Now, I tried it but is now giving me an error `Token Comma expected` at the `then` statement on the `New Query`, any thoughts?

`New Query`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="URL_Table"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each [Wait] = "yes" then WaitMinutes(Number.RandomBetween(60,90), () => fGetResults([URL_List])) else fGetResults([URL_List]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

#############
UPDATE2
#############

I think I found the issue. Simply forgot the "if" on the if-then-else statement. The only thing is, there maybe a more elegant solution for this but this works for now. Let me know if you have a more efficient solution. Thank you.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="URL_Table"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if [Wait] = "yes" then WaitMinutes(Number.RandomBetween(60,90), () => fGetResults([URL_List])) else fGetResults([URL_List]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

#############
UPDATE3: SOLUTION
#############

More problems, I think my usage for minutes is not correct but followed exactly what the website said and used seconds and removed the random function on the Query.

`WaitSeconds` function:

```
let
    Wait = (seconds as number, action as function) => 
            if (List.Count(List.Generate(() => DateTimeZone.LocalNow() + #duration(0,0,0,seconds), (x) => DateTimeZone.LocalNow() < x, (x) => x)) = 0) then null else action()
in
    Wait
```

Query (15mins seems to work which is same as 900sec):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="URL_Table"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if [Wait] = "yes" then WaitSeconds(900, () => fGetResults([URL_List])) else fGetResults([URL_List]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: You can interact with `PowerQuery` in `VBA`. Do you have any VBA background?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo for responding. I know a little bit of VBA (not a programmer at all) but willing to learn if you can point me in the right direction. Thank you. Also, I am closer to a solution, see my updates above.

Comment: OK, i figured this out myself (I feel like an idiot posting a question that I eventually answered). I missed the "if" portion of the if-then-else.

Comment: Great. Remember that you can always post your own answer and mark it so others in the same situation may find it.